# Android DB controller error

Tags: android, database

Hello everyone :) can you explain why I get this [image: error] and tell me what how I have to change my code. Waiting for the answers. Have a nice day:)

Comment: post code instead of picture...!

Comment: I think its simple mistake, and picture will be enough

Comment: Please copy and paste your code and error message here.

Comment: non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: But why in other activities I can call it?

Comment: @RytisVanagas Call what?

Answer (score 0):

```
controller
```

cannot be used in a static method. You need to make the controller object static to be able to use in a static method.

Comment: But why in other activities I can call it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to use a non-static member field inside a static method. This is not allowed since you need an instance of the class to access the member field. You have two choices:

1. Make the member field a static class variable by adding the `static` modifier to its declaration.
2. Remove the `static` modifier from the method to make it non-static.

You should definitely prefer the second solution over the first. As a general rule of thumb, all methods and variables should be non-static unless you have a very good, specific reason to make them static. One common use of static variables is for final constants. You also might find a situation where all instances of a class share a single value. Note that these are the exception, not the rule.